# Mouseover submenu broke

Tags: html, css, mouseover, submenu

I had a mouseover submenu working very nicely on my site (so nicely in fact that it was working exactly right in Chrome, IE 7 & 8, and FF), but now it's broken somehow and I can't see the problem.

Here's the CSS:

```
.MainMenu {
    width: 90% !important;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 42px !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #0054a6;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0054a6;
    background: transparent url("Images/ServiceMenuBG.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.MainMenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.MainMenu li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: 31px;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 11px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid #0054a6;
}
.MainMenuItem#First { border-left: 1px solid #0054a6; }
.MainMenuItem a {
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    height: 31px;
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.MainMenuItem:hover { background: transparent url("Images/ServiceMenuBG.png") repeat-x 0 -42px; }
.SubMenu {
    z-index: 500;
    display: none;
    width: 150px !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(51,118,184);
}
.SubMenu li { padding: 0 0 2px 5px; height: 20px !important; width: 143px; }
.SubMenu li a {
    height: 20px !important;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.SubMenu li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
.MainMenu li.MainMenuItem>ul { top: auto; left: auto; }
.MainMenu li.MainMenuItem:hover ul { display: block; }'
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="MainMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="MainMenuItem" id="First"><a href="~/Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li class="MainMenuItem"><a href="Pages/Philosophies.aspx">Philosophies</a></li>
        <li class="MainMenuItem"><a href="Pages/Services.aspx#top">Services</a>
            <ul class="SubMenu">
                <li id="TopItem"><a href="Pages/Services.aspx#shop">Shop Repair</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pages/Services.aspx#donations">Donations</a></li>
                <li><a href="Pages/Services.aspx#consulting">Consulting</a></li>
                <li id="BottomItem"><a href="Pages/Services.aspx#on-site">On-site Service</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="MainMenuItem"><a href="Pages/Contracts.aspx">Contracts</a></li>
        <li class="MainMenuItem"><a href="Pages/AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="MainMenuItem"><a href="Pages/ContactUs.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The SubMenu doesn't display either on mouseover or if I set it's initial `display` property to `block`. It's as if it doesn't exist on the page at all.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but I noticed that you use ID attributes for things that should really be class names, e.g. the "TopItem" element. Only use IDs on things that are unique to the entire document.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you get the feeling that it doesn't exist because you have `.MainMenuItem a {color: #ffffff;}` ? just a thought. a live example would help better to understand the problem.

Comment: @Deniz
`TopItem`, `First`, and `BottomItem` in the code are only used in those places on the page. This code comes from an asp.net master page so it's used everywhere on the site. These names aren't used anywhere else. Just thought I'd clear that up.

Comment: Well, alright then! :) Save it for when the specification changes, which it inevitably will. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.MainMenu { overflow: hidden; }
```

is hiding the sub menus, so remove that line. Line 6 in your CSS.

As Sotiris mentioned

```
.MainMenuItem a { color: #ffffff; }
```

hides the top menu items (maybe not on your version because I see you have a background image)

Comment: That's ok :)
The only reason I could see would be in case the text goes outside the menu title area. If that's the case you could apply the overflow:hidden; to the actual link instead, as in
.MainMenu a { overflow: hidden; }
This will apply to all the child menu items too.
Hope that helps.